# how to iterate two different lists parallelly, converges to one

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

```
a = [1, 2, 7, 5, 11]
b = [3, 4, 5, 11]
```

above example is related to

```
(1)-->(2)-->(7)-->(5)--(11)

                /
(3) -->(4) ----
```

here node 5 is merging point of two list.

Comment: Use zip(a,b)....

Comment: What is needed result?

Comment: @MBo i want my loop to wait at point 5, and after 5, i want to only one loop not both

Comment: So you want to find common tail? Does it always exist? Is case of common subarray with different tails possible? Like `[1, 2, 7, 5, 11, 21]+[3, 4, 5, 11,16]`

Comment: @MBo No, actually there are two different data sets (one at 1 and other at 3), and few function are being applied as sequence shown and then  at 5 two data sets become one dataset, as it merging at 5,  and then going to 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For case of guaranteeed common tail:

Iterate both these lists in reverse direction, from the ends, until difference is discovered. Remember indexes of the common tail start.

Now, if needed, traverse beginning of both lists before junction point.

---

Alternative way - if strict ordering exists:

At every step go ahead in the list with **smaller current element**